# \app\src\main\res\drawable\ic_launcher_foreground.xml: AAPT: error: <adaptive-icon> elements require a sdk version of at least 26

Tags: android

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> ERROR:C:\Users\Desktop\App Name\app\src\main\res\drawable\ic_launcher_foreground.xml: AAPT: error:  elements require a sdk version of at least 26.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: This rather is `drawable-v26`.

Comment: SO PLEASE HOW CAN I MAKE THE APP RUN ON MINSDK21